# function return undefined value

Tags: javascript, function, dom, return

I have some piece of code which I want to use to validation of quantity of email in text field

```
  function lockSubmits(selector,value){

      var submitInputs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

      for(var j = 0; j<=submitInputs.length; j++){

        submitInputs[j].disabled = value;
      }

  }

  function checkQuantity(tested,sign){

      var testedField = document.querySelector(tested);
      var mailCounter = 0;

      for(var i=0; i<testedField.value.length; i++){
        if(testedField.value[i] == '@'){
          mailCounter += 1;
        }
        return mailCounter;
      }

  }





  var eventField = document.querySelector('#tag_email_list');
  var alertCounter = false;




  eventField.addEventListener('input',function(){

      // var mailCounter = 0;

      // for(var i=0; i<testedField.value.length; i++){
      //   if(testedField.value[i] == '@'){
      //     mailCounter += 1;
      //   }
      // }

      checkQuantity('#tag_email_list','@');


     if((!alertCounter) && (mailCounter >= 999)){
      alert('<%= tt('tag.email_list_lock') %>');
      lockSubmits('input[type="submit"]', true);
      alertCounter = true;
     }

     if(mailCounter<= 999){
      lockSubmits('input[type="submit"]', false);
      alertCounter = false;
     }
  })
```

my trouble is that my code is stopped on line:

```
if((!alertCounter) && (mailCounter >= 999))
```

exactly on checking if mailCounter is greater or equal than 999, any advices what is going on? does the return mailCounter should return mailCounter value? now it`s returned refferenceError: mail Counter is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return value of your invocation of `checkQuantity` to a variable. `mailCounter` is scoped to within the function in which it is defined, so if you trying to reference it will cause a referenceError.

```
var mailCounter = checkQuantity('#tag_email_list','@');

if(!alertCounter && mailCounter >= 999) {
    ...
}
```

Similarly, you'll need to do the same in your second `if` statement.

```
if(mailCounter <= 999) { ... }
```

By the way, you do realize that if `mailCounter` is exactly `999`, both `mailCounter >= 999` and `mailCounter <= 999` evaluate to `true`? Might want to look into this - in such a case, your code will disable the inputs, then immediately un-disable them, since both `if` blocks will be executed. Perhaps you meant to check for strict inequality?

```
if(mailCounter < 999) { ... }
```

Comment: any examples or words routing me on 'assigning the return value of your invocation of chec Quanttity to a variable?' you mean var zmienna = checkQuantity(args) and next check zmienna in if statement?

Comment: I think no because I tried var checkQuantity = function(tested,sign){ **the code** } and it still return the same error

Comment: ok, thats working but now mailCounter is always one, no matter if there is more than one '@'...

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for your issues with mailCounter, as it is out of the scope of this current question. Glad you got the undefined issue worked out.